# Excel Pivot table with R (adding totals and %) instead of counts - MRE included

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to recreate a Pivot table in R (as the output I get from Excel). So far this is how my code looks like:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
reason <-  c("A","A","A","B","B")
type <- c("1. Small","1. Small","1. Mid","1. Mid","1. Small")

df <- data.frame(id,reason,type)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(reason, type) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% ungroup()
df3 <- df2 %>% dcast(type ~ reason, value.var = "count")
```

Resulting df3 gets me the counts and expected structure, but I'm missing a total column and %. So the expected result should be:

```
type     Total   A     B
1. Small 60%     66%   50%
2. Mid   40%     33%   50%
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
type      A     B
1. Small  2     1
2. Mid    1     1
```

Is it possible to tweak the code to get the expected result? or is there another function in R that I'm missing?

Thx!

Comment: do you need a `tidyverse` or `data.table` solution

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   count(reason, type) %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   mutate(prop = 100 *n/sum(n), Total = 100 * sum(n)/sum(.$n)) %>% 
   select(-n) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = reason, values_from = prop)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  type     Total     A     B
#  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1. Mid      40  50    50  
#2 1. Small    60  66.7  33.3
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- setDT(df)[, .N, .(reason, type)]
dcast(dt1[, c('prop', 'Total') := .(100 * N/sum(N), 
   100 * sum(N)/sum(dt1$N)), type], type + Total ~ reason, value.var = 'prop')
#      type Total        A        B
#1:   1. Mid    40 50.00000 50.00000
#2: 1. Small    60 66.66667 33.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do so

```
library(tidiverse)
xtabs(count ~ type + reason, df2) %>% 
addmargins(margin = 2) %>% 
prop.table(margin = 2) %>% 
round(digits = 3)
```

Comment: It works on the console, however when saving as a df structure gets messed up:  

df3 <- as.data.frame(xtabs(count ~ type + reason, df2) %>% 
    addmargins(margin = 2) %>% 
    prop.table(margin = 2) %>% 
    round(digits = 3))